# how to write write a set for unordered pair in Java

Tags: java

I need to have a Set (HashSet) such that if I insert a pair `(a, b)` and if `(b, a)` is already in the set, the insertion would just be ignored. How to do this in Java?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, it depends on the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method of your `Pair` class.  They need to ignore order.

`Set` itself is a good example of a class which ignores order for equality--you can look at the code of [`AbstractSet`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28Object%29).  If the order of the pair doesn't matter even outside of equality comparison, you can just store `HashSet`s (each with two elements) in your set.  It would be best to wrap it in a datatype:

```
 public class UnorderedPair<T> {
     private final Set<T> set;

     public UnorderedPair(T a, T b) {
          set = new HashSet<T>();
          set.add(a);
          set.add(b);
     }

     public boolean equals(Object b) {
         //...delegate to set
     }

     public int hashCode() {
         return set.hashCode();
     }
}
```

Comment: although it's not mentioned in the OP, would this would fail if you tried saving the set `(a, a)`?

Comment: @Justin: I guess it depends on your requirements.  `new UnorderedPair(a, a).equals(new UnorderedPair(a, a))` should still return true (the set will just have one element).  Further, `new UnorderedPair(a, a).equals(new UnorderedPair(a, null))` should return false, as nulls are still valid entries in a `HashSet`. I personally like @erickson's variation of not allowing that to start with.

Comment: I would suggest using `Set.of(a, b)` instead of a `HashSet` as it creates a `Set` specifically designed for 2 (or 1) elements.

Answer (score 11):

As none of the answers mentions this approach, I'd like to add this approach:

```java
public class UnorderedPair<T> {
    final T first, second;

    public UnorderedPair(T first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof UnorderedPair))
            return false;
        UnorderedPair<T> up = (UnorderedPair<T>) o;
        return (up.first == this.first && up.second == this.second) ||
                (up.first == this.second && up.second == this.first);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashFirst = first.hashCode();
        int hashSecond = second.hashCode();
        int maxHash = Math.max(hashFirst, hashSecond);
        int minHash = Math.min(hashFirst, hashSecond);
        // return Objects.hash(minHash, maxHash);
        // the above line also works but I tend to avoid this to avoid unnecessary auto-boxing
        return minHash * 31 + maxHash;
    }
}
```

Note that the general contract of the `hashCode()` and `equals()` should be followed:

- If you are overriding either `hashCode()` or `equals()` you usually have to also override the other method.
- If the `equals` return `true` for 2 objects, then the `hashCode()` method must return the same `int` for both the objects.
- If the `hashCode()` returns same `int` for 2 objects, then it's not necessarily true that the `equals()` method return `true`.

The above implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` method ensures this.

Answer (score 3):

```
final class Pair<T> {
  private final Set<T> elements = new LinkedHashSet<T>();
  Pair(T a, T b) {
    elements.add(a);
    if (!elements.add(b))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return elements.hashCode();
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this)
      return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof Pair<?>))
      return false;
    return elements.equals(((Pair<?>) obj).elements);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using a `Set` means that `a` and `b` cannot be equal.

Comment: As I've written the constructor, this isn't allowed. But if you take out the explicit check, `a` and `b` could be the same object, and everything would still work.

Answer (score 2):

Define a class `Pair` whose `equals` and `hashCode` methods are based on both `a` and `b` in the way that the order of `a` and `b` does not matter and use a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of the `Pair` class to treat both (a,b) and (b,a) as equal.

Comment: Overriding `hashCode()` is also necessary.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild yes thats a given

Comment: Not for someone who doesn't see how to implement a tuple that can be used as a hash key.