# Find shortest route between points in 2d from collection

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have a list of 2D points on my scene and i have an array of connections between these Points stored as unordered pairs

Pair is defined exactly as here [how to write write a set for unordered pair in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905528/how-to-write-write-a-set-for-unordered-pair-in-java)

so i have :

```
ArrayList<PointF> mPoints = new ArrayList<PointF>();

ArrayList<Pair<PointF>> mConnections = new ArrayList<Pair<PointF>>();

//
PointF mStartPoint = mPoints.get(0);
PointF mEndPoint = mPoints.get(80);
```

I need to find array of Points which will lead me from source to destination Point.

I think to add to each Pair information about distance but what next ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of a standard [path finding problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding).

If you need a guaranteed exact solution, go with something like [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). If you need something more efficient, but can live with suboptimal solutions for certain cases, go with the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a).

Answer (score 1):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstras_algorithm#Algorithm for a solution.